# How we can access to the injector object from inside of a dependency class?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

With Autofac, how we can access to the activator class from inside of a dependency class?

for example we have two classes `A` and `B` which the class `A` injects the `B`. so I want to access to reference of object of `A` from `B`'s constructor:

```
public class A
{
   private readonly B _b;
   public A(B b)
   {
      _b = b;
   }
}

public class B
{
   public B( ... )
   {
       //  in here i want to access to the reference of
       //  the object which injects this class,
       //  (which in this example is the 'A')

   }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: This is a bad design which is notoriously known as "circular dependency". You should consider re-designing your code so that it doesn't need `A` instance.

Comment: B does not need a new instance of A. it just need the current instance of A which injects the B. actually the B is going to know which class is injecting it to do some special jobs for it.

Comment: @AliAdl - this is exactly what is meant by "bad design". `B` should never (need to) know which `A` uses it. -- on the other hand, maybe you just got it the wrong way. If `B` needs to know `A` but `A` does *not* need to know about `B`, then instance of `B` should just get instance of `A` in its constructor. If really `A` needs `B` *and* `B` needs `A` you very likely have a design problem. If you elaborate a bit more what you're trying to accomplish we might be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: Without any concrete code of your actual problem, it will be impossible for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that, you should consider re-designing *A*, circular dependencies will make your life more difficult. Has the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle been respected ? Splitting *A* to different classes may be the solution.

By the way, if you really want to do that, **which I strongly disrecommend**, you can use `Lazy<A>`

```
class A
{
    private readonly B _b;
    public A(B b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
}

class B
{
    public B(Lazy<A> a)
    {
        this._a = a;
    }

    private readonly Lazy<A> _a;
}
```

Of course, you won't be able to access value of *A* inside constructor of *B* but you will be able to access *A* on *B* methods.

Comment: This isn't certainly going to to what OP needs if `A` is instance per dependency scope. OP's comment says that he needs the same instance which is used by the dependency.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's right. I'm thinking of something using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645099/identify-the-dependency-resolving-an-instance-ioc-autofac/28646750#28646750

Comment: @Cryil thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it is not actually what i want :(. Sriram is right.

Comment: @AliAdl could you use proxy ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand please let me know details about proxy, and explain what is that?

Comment: @AliAdl I was thinking about http://castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy and call a `Initialize` method on `B` while `A` is being constructed. Unfortunately it seems that you can't intercept constructor using castle dynamicproxy. You can do your own proxy but it quite difficult